# linux + fstab + cifs

Tags: linux, cifs

I get the following line that need to add to the `/etc/fstab` in redhat 6

in order to mount  **//ytur.co.lm/Project/0203_PLA-NET /exp/gt/win**

```
//ytur.co.lm/Project/0203_PLA-NET /exp/gt/win cifs username=juhdf,codepage=cp932,iocharset=utf8,password=ploefdd 0 0
```

Will this syntax work with cifs?